# do not add the data to array if data is equal to zero in vb6

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vb6

Here is my code:

```
i=0
ReDim Preserve cashflowValues(i)
cashflowValues(0) = loanAmount
Do Until adors.EOF
      ReDim Preserve cashflowValues(i)
      IF adors!CashFlow <> 0 Then
          cashflowValues(i) = adors!CashFlow
          End If
          adors.MoveNext
          i = i + 1
    Loop
```

But still zero value is added to array. What is wrong with my code? Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance for those who help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` has to be incremented only when the value is added to the array. Something like

```
IF adors!CashFlow <> 0 Then
    cashflowValues(i) = adors!CashFlow
    i = i + 1
End If
adors.MoveNext
```

Comment: I would also mention that I would have thought that the ReDim Preserve cashflowValues(i) line in the loop should only be called when adding a new item. On the other hand, I would try to avoid using ReDim Preserve, and wherever possibly pre-allocate the size of the array (using Preserve is a slow operation). Alternatively, use the VBA.Collection class.